# Is dynamic addition of values to a set possible in Integer Linear Programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

$X_{it}$ is a binary decision variable. Need to construct a set $V_t$ such that if $X_{it}$ = $1$ then i is an element of set $V_t$. Is it possible to formulate this in integer linear programming? if so please guide me. thanks.

Comment: you should  explain  your problem better. $X_{i,t} \in \{0,1\}$ are some of the variables of your minimization problem, and if $X_{i,t} = 1$ then what ?

Comment: @user1952009 sorry for not explaining properly. The Set V of index t should contain all values of i satisfying the condition.

Comment: what that set is used for ? ... as a constraint for another variable $y_t \in V_t$ ?

Comment: The set helps me to constraint another decision variable. The values of the set are passed as the index for other constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_i$ be a binary variable that equals $1$ if and only if $i$ is an element of $V_t$. Adding the following constraint should do the trick:
$$
 X_{it}\le y_i
$$
Indeed, if $X_{it}=1$, then it forces $y_i$ to take value $1$, which means $i$ will be in the set $V_t$.

Comment: is there a way to add values to set $V_t$ directly. That is $V_1$={1,2,3} for $X_{11}$=$X_{21}$=$X_{31}$=$1$.

Comment: The one way implication $X_{i,t}\le y_i$ leaves $y_i$ free to float when $X_{i,t}=0$. Depending on the situation, that may lead to unintended results.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen Completely true, but without more knowledge of the problem it is difficult to be more precise. I would suggest adding a term in objective function to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Kuifje Then you are solving a different problem (so possibly no longer optimal solutions).

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen In this case I would replace the $\le$ sign by a $=$, but I guess that's not very interesting. Might as well leave the problem as it is, and inspect the variables $X_{it}$. Again, without knowledge of the whole problem, it is difficult to give a good response. This being said thanks for you comments! What would you suggest?

Comment: @Kuifje I have no clue. I don't know what the poster wants to do with his 'set'. Probably we end up with a multiplication with a binary variable anyway.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen i want to use the elements of the set as the index for another decision variable in a different constraint.

Comment: You can't index by a variable in linear programming. In Constraint Programming there is actually such a concept as indexing by a variable, but I even doubt that would help you. Let $v_i \in \{0,1\}$ be your binary variable. Then I don't know even know what $x_{v_i}$ is. I think what you want is something like $\sum_{i|(v_i=1)} x_i$ (I am just guessing because you don't want to tell us). That can be written as $\sum_i v_i x_i$ (often such a thing can be further linearized).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen you are right.Can you help me to convert $\sum_i v_i x_i$ in linear form? thanks.

Comment: We don't know exactly what $x$ is (binary, integer, continuous). So with all these secrets, I really can not provide the best advice.

Comment: $x$ is binary and $\sum_i v_i x_i$ <= Constant.

Comment: Make it $\sum_i y_i \le C$, $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ and add the constraints $y_i\ge x_i+v_i-1$. If needed we can relax $y$ to be continuous between 0 and 1.